# how to set windows service in hudson 1.398

Tags: windows-services, hudson

I just looking Hudson two days ago. So i am very newbie.

I download hudson 1.398, searching about windows service. But in manage Hudson there doens't have install as windows service like other version. How i can make it in hudon 1.398.

And there any good tutorial, easy to understand, and full complete tutorial..

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

owh i see the problem. Because i use tomcat to extract hudson.war. And the tomcat is a service. So hudson will not need other service. and windows service gone. Just stop tomcat and use manual java -jar hudson.war from cmd. there's has option for windows service.

Thank's for everyone.. Hope help you all.

Answer (score 0):

From the wiki: [Installing Hudson as a Windows Service](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Installing+Hudson+as+a+Windows+service). Make sure .NET 2.0 is installed (on the server, I presume).

Comment: yes i have opened that page, but that's have some problem. I don't have option for install as windows service. Like i said...