# Hudson 1.398 on Windows 7 doesn't have Install as Windows Service option

Tags: windows-7, windows-services, hudson

I realize this is very similar to this question: [how to set windows service in hudson 1.398](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400089/how-to-set-windows-service-in-hudson-1-398) but that solution did not work or seem to apply in my case.

I'm a Hudson noob. I downloaded the .war file from the Hudson site. I tried using these two pages as guides:
http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Installing+Hudson+as+a+Windows+service

http://java.dzone.com/articles/installing-hudson-windows

I then extract the war using "java -jar hudson.war" from the command line. I've tried opening the command line normally and running as admin.

I navigate to http://localhost:8080, then click on "Manage Hudson", but I don't have an option for "Install as Windows Service". I'm using my local Windows 7 Ultimate N 64-bit. I have .NET Framework version 4 installed. What am I doing wrong that causes this option not to appear?

Comment: Do you have UAC enabled? Can you try it with UAC disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an issue others are experiencing as well. Maybe file a bug at

http://issues.hudson-ci.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa

As a workaround you can just use the Java Service Wrapper and set it up manually. It is pretty trivial to do and there is excellent documentation right there on the site.

http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp

Comment: Here is a related question btw. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400089/how-to-set-windows-service-in-hudson-1-398

Comment: The bug is now fixed and will be part of the next release. http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-8786

Answer (score 5):

You can also use [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/), where most of the former Hudson developers work (see [this](http://jenkins-ci.org/why)), which now has a Windows installer.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with v. 1.398.

I then tried to install v. 1.348 (cause we have that version running on another machine), I then got the option to "Install as Windows Service" which I did and then I upgraded to newest version (my case 1.398).

(another thing, if possible consider using Jenkins, at least its simpler to install the service on a windows machine)